# linear independence and field extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

suppose $K|F$ is a field extension & $\alpha \in K$ is such that $[F(\alpha):F]>=n$,

if $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ are distinct scalars of $F$,prove that $\frac{1}{\alpha-\lambda_1},...,\frac{1}{\alpha-\lambda_n}$ are linear independent over $F$.

from $[F(\alpha):F]>=n$ i get that $\alpha$ is not the root of a polynomial over $F$ with degree less than $n$ and
i did a lot of calculation and play with the equation,but i failed.

is there any hint?

thank you.

Comment: I found another solution, but I don't want to type up the details: multiply $\alpha-x$ by an $n-1$ degree polynomial in $\alpha$ with coefficients rational functions of $x$. You will get a recurrence relation that determines the coefficients by setting the product equal to $1$. You then replace each $\frac{1}{\alpha-\lambda_j}$ with this polynomial. Then you get a matrix in the $\lambda_j$'s which factors as an invertible triangular matrix times the Vandermonde matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set an arbitrary $F$-linear combination of the $\frac{1}{\alpha-\lambda_i}$'s equal to zero and multiply by the product of the $\alpha-\lambda_i$'s, then you get an $n-1$ degree polynomial in $\alpha$ equal to zero. Thus the polynomial is zero. (The product of the $\alpha-\lambda_i$'s is not zero because $\alpha$ is not in $F$.)

edit:

Let $\sigma_{i,n}$ be the $i$th elementary symmetric polynomial on $n$ variables.

$
\begin{align*}
0 &=\sum_{k=1}^nA_k\prod_{1\leq j\leq n,j\neq k}(\alpha-\lambda_j)\\
 &=\sum_{k=1}^nA_k\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-1-i}\sigma_{i,n-1}(\lambda_j;1\leq j\leq n,j\neq k)\alpha^i\\
 &=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left[\sum_{k=1}^nA_k(-1)^{n-1-i}\sigma_{i,n-1}(\lambda_j;1\leq j\leq n,j\neq k)\right]\alpha^i
\end{align*}
$

Since $[F(\alpha):F]\geq n$, we know that all the coefficients are $0$.

So $\sum_{k=1}^nA_k(-1)^{n-1-i}\sigma_{i,n-1}(\lambda_j;1\leq j\leq n,j\neq k)=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n-1$. Let's apply Gaussian elimination to the matrix

$
M_n=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -\sum_{j\neq 1}\lambda_j & \sum_{1\leq j_1<j_2\leq n,j\neq 1}\lambda_{j_1}\lambda_{j_2} &\cdots & (-1)^{n-1}\prod_{j\neq 1}\lambda_{j}\\
1 & -\sum_{j\neq 2}\lambda_j & \sum_{1\leq j_1<j_2\leq n,j\neq 2}\lambda_{j_1}\lambda_{j_2} &\cdots & (-1)^{n-1}\prod_{j\neq 2}\lambda_{j}\\
1 & -\sum_{j\neq 3}\lambda_j & \sum_{1\leq j_1<j_2\leq n,j\neq 3}\lambda_{j_1}\lambda_{j_2} &\cdots & (-1)^{n-1}\prod_{j\neq 3}\lambda_{j}\\
1 & -\sum_{j\neq 4}\lambda_j & \sum_{1\leq j_1<j_2\leq n,j\neq 4}\lambda_{j_1}\lambda_{j_2} &\cdots & (-1)^{n-1}\prod_{j\neq 4}\lambda_{j}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots\\
1 & -\sum_{j\neq n}\lambda_j & \sum_{1\leq j_1<j_2\leq n,j\neq n}\lambda_{j_1}\lambda_{j_2} &\cdots & (-1)^{n-1}\prod_{j\neq n}\lambda_{j}\\
\end{array}\right]
$

Subtracting the first row from all the others gives

$
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -\sum_{j\neq 1}\lambda_j & \sum_{1\leq j_1<j_2\leq n,j\neq 1}\lambda_{j_1}\lambda_{j_2} &\cdots & (-1)^{n-1}\prod_{j\neq 1}\lambda_{j}\\
0 & \lambda_2-\lambda_1 & -(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)\sum_{j\neq 2}\lambda_j &\cdots & (-1)^{n-2}(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)\sum_{1\leq j_1<\ldots<j_{n-2}\leq n,j\neq 2}\prod_{1\leq i\leq n-2}\lambda_{j_i}\\
0 & \lambda_3-\lambda_1 & -(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)\sum_{j\neq 3}\lambda_j &\cdots & (-1)^{n-2}(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)\sum_{1\leq j_1<\ldots<j_{n-2}\leq n,j\neq 3}\prod_{1\leq i\leq n-2}\lambda_{j_i}\\
0 & \lambda_4-\lambda_1 & -(\lambda_4-\lambda_1)\sum_{j\neq 4}\lambda_j &\cdots & (-1)^{n-2}(\lambda_4-\lambda_1)\sum_{1\leq j_1<\ldots<j_{n-2}\leq n,j\neq 4}\prod_{1\leq i\leq n-2}\lambda_{j_i}\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots\\
0 & \lambda_n-\lambda_1 & -(\lambda_n-\lambda_1)\sum_{j\neq n}\lambda_j &\cdots & (-1)^{n-2}(\lambda_n-\lambda_1)\sum_{1\leq j_1<\ldots<j_{n-2}\leq n,j\neq n}\prod_{1\leq i\leq n-2}\lambda_{j_i}\\
\end{array}\right]
$

Since the $\lambda$'s are all distinct, we can divide each row by $\lambda_k-\lambda_1$ without affecting the invertibility of the matrix. By induction, we see that this matrix is invertible. Thus all the $A_k$'s must be zero.

I think that this matrix is related to the inverse of the Vandermonde matrix, but I'm not sure how.

edit2: The induction proof. The $1\times 1$ case is the matrix $[1]$, which is invertible. Suppose that the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrix $M_{n-1}$ is invertible. Then the $n\times n$ matrix $M_n$ given above has $\det M_n=\left(\prod_{k\neq 1}\lambda_1-\lambda_k)\right)\det M_{n-1}$ by the row reduction shown above. Since the $\lambda$'s are distinct and $\det M_{n-1}\neq 0$, we see that $\det M_n\neq 0$ as well.

edit3: I'll demonstrate the $2\times2$ and $3\times3$ cases:

$\det M_2=\left\vert\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -\lambda_2\\
1 & -\lambda_1\\
\end{array}\right\vert=\left\vert\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -\lambda_2\\
0 & \lambda_2-\lambda_1\\
\end{array}\right\vert=\lambda_2-\lambda_1
$

and

$\det M_3=\left\vert\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -(\lambda_2+\lambda_3) & \lambda_2\lambda_3\\
1 & -(\lambda_3+\lambda_1) & \lambda_3\lambda_1\\
1 & -(\lambda_1+\lambda_2) & \lambda_1\lambda_2\\
\end{array}\right\vert=\left\vert\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -(\lambda_2+\lambda_3) & \lambda_2\lambda_3\\
0 & \lambda_2-\lambda_1 & -(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)\lambda_3\\
0 & \lambda_3-\lambda_1 & -(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)\lambda_2\\
\end{array}\right\vert=(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)\left\vert\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -(\lambda_2+\lambda_3) & \lambda_2\lambda_3\\
0 & 1 & -\lambda_3\\
0 & 1 & -\lambda_2\\
\end{array}\right\vert=(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)(\lambda_3-\lambda_2)
$

Note that the $2\times 2$ minor of $M_3$ is a copy of $M_2$. So $\det M_3=(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)(\lambda_3-\lambda_1)\det M_2$

Comment: yes i did,but i think this doesn't work

Comment: What issue did you run into?

Comment: we have $A_1(\alpha-\lambda_2)...(\alpha-\lambda_n)+...+A_n(\alpha-\lambda_1)...(\alpha-\lambda_{n-1})=0$,but how can i conclude $A_i$'s are all zero? i know that it is a polynomial with degree $n-1$ so all the coefficients must be zero

Comment: Taylor thanks but what do u mean $σi,n$?

Comment: $\sigma_{i,n}$ is the $i$th elementary symmetric polynomial on $n$ variables. One definition is $$\prod_{k=1}^n(t-x_k)=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{n-i}\sigma_it^i.$$ You can read more about them on wikipedia (though I'm indexing them differently): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial

Comment: Also, the entries of the first matrix should tell you what I mean.

Comment: is it easy to prove the invertability of that matrix by induction?

Comment: I'll add that to the post.

Comment: Taylor thank u a lot but i didn't understand how did u calculate $det M_n$.by row reduction it won't be what you said i think.

Comment: I'll demonstrate the $2\times 2$ and $3\times3$ cases for you.